# A: greendao method loadAll() to Large return

Tags: greendao

I use loadAll method, my list real on db is 10, but the return list size is too large, around 100 more

```
entityDao = daoSession.getEntityDao();

List<Entity> listEntities = entityDao.loadAll();
```

listEntities.Size() = too large

Comment: so what is your query?

Comment: Probably there is something wrong with how you insert or update your data. Please post your schema and your code updateing, inserting and querying `Entity`.

Comment: Greendao isn't inserting duplicate entries by accident. I'm pretty sure the problem lies either in your schema-creation or in the way you update or insert your data. If you want someone to be able to help you you should post this information.